# Read .txt file with missing information as pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read a .txt file as a panda dataframe, however I'm getting several errors and the data is not loading. The problem that I found has to do with the structure of the data.

```
file.txt:
    "Mark","Company","Country","Value","1","abcdef","ecu","1000","","","usa","30","","","col","200"....
```

The file.txt displays information as follows:

```
Mark          Company     Country     Value   ...
   1           abcdef         ecu      1000   ...
                              usa        30   ...
                              col       200   ...
   2           ghijk          jap        10   ...
                              eur       900   ...
                              lki             ...
   3           lmnop          wer        21   ...
                              uye             ...
                              urg       123   ...
   .               .            .         .     .     
   .               .            .         .     .
```

What I need is a dataframe with a structure similar to this:

```
Mark          Company     Country     Value   ...
   1           abcdef         ecu      1000   ...
   1           abcdef         usa        30   ...
   1           abcdef         col       200   ...
   2           ghijk          jap        10   ...
   2           ghijk          eur       900   ...
   2           ghijk          lki         0   ...
   3           lmnop          wer        21   ...
   3           lmnop          uye         0   ...
   3           lmnop          urg       123   ...
   .               .            .         .     .     
   .               .            .         .     .
```

Comment: Simplest fix might be to write a short script to clean up your data first.

Comment: You can not read the txt file in as the table you are showing, can you show how your txt file looks like including the new line?

Comment: @Psidom the file.txt something looks like this:
"Mark","Company","Country","Value"
"1","abcdef","ecu","1000"
"","","usa","30"
"","","col","200"
"2","ghijk","jap","10"
"","","eur","900"
"","","lki",""
"3","lmnop","wer","21"
"","","uye",""
"","","urg","123"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
df = pd.read_csv(fn,
                 encoding='utf-16',
                 na_values=['NA','NaN','nan','n.a.'],
                 low_memory=False)

# list here ALL columns that must be filled, using `ffill()` method:
cols = ['Mark','Company name','Cons. code','City']
df[cols] = df[cols].ffill()

# assuming that we have `ffilled` all required columns, we can simply `fillna(0)` for the rest of the columns
df = df.fillna(0)
```

---

**OLD answer:**

Your file looks like a fixed width file, so try to use [pd.read_fwf](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html) in conjunction with [DataFrame.ffill()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html)

Assuming we have the following TXT file:

```
Mark          Company     Country     Value1  Value2 
   1           abcdef         ecu      1000      
                              usa        30      10  
                              col       200      20  
   2           ghijk          jap        10        
                              eur       900      30  
                              lki                40    
   3           lmnop          wer        21        
                              uye               50     
                              urg       123
```

Solution:

```
In [102]: fn = r'D:\temp\.data\002.txt'

In [103]: df = pd.read_fwf(fn)

In [123]: df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains(r'^Value')] = df.filter(regex=r'^Value').fillna(0)

In [124]: df = df.ffill()

In [125]: df
Out[125]:
   Mark Company Country  Value1  Value2
0   1.0  abcdef     ecu  1000.0     0.0
1   1.0  abcdef     usa    30.0    10.0
2   1.0  abcdef     col   200.0    20.0
3   2.0   ghijk     jap    10.0     0.0
4   2.0   ghijk     eur   900.0    30.0
5   2.0   ghijk     lki     0.0    40.0
6   3.0   lmnop     wer    21.0     0.0
7   3.0   lmnop     uye     0.0    50.0
8   3.0   lmnop     urg   123.0     0.0
```

Comment: Tks MaxU... but the original file is a .txt / Also, in the value column where there are no values, they have to be 0. Do you know how to solve that?

Comment: One more thing... in the example I show you there is only one column 'value', however in my data there are almost 100 columns with values (Value1...valueN). Is there a way to manage that?

Comment: @PAstudilloE, sure, check updated answer. Please next time try to provide a reproducible samples... ;-)

Comment: tks a lot!!! it's working... however, I'm having an issue: the first line that I'm getting (after displaying the df) is weird. 

The original file is like this:

"Mark","Company name","NACE Rev. 2 Core code (4 digits)",......

but the DF is placing all the header line as if everything was a single column like this: 

��"Mark","Company name","NACE Rev. 2 Core code (4 digits)","

Comment: It looks like a UTF BOM signature, so try this: `df = pd.read_fwf(fn, encoding='utf-16')`

Comment: I'm still getting the same result =(

Comment: @PAstudilloE, i afraid i would need a reproducible file in order to be able to help you...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138489/discussion-between-maxu-and-pastudilloe).

Comment: I manage to process my data. However, at the end I'm trying to convert the outcome to a single .csv / Once I compiled everything, after I do this: dfs.to_csv('/Users/pastudilloe/Orbis_Total.csv', index=False) I'm getting this error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)       
Do you know what's happening?